# Getting DataSource object from JNDI context in a Standalone Java Application?

Tags: java, datasource, jndi

I downloaded the fscontext.jar file from [here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/f/Downloadfscontextjar.htm) and put it in my classpath.

This is the code I have:

```
import javax.naming.*;
import java.io.File;

public class JNDIHello {

    final static String URL =
            "file:///Users/Koray Tugay/Development/studentform/src/main/java/biz/tugay";
    final static String CONTEXT_FACTORY
            = "com.sun.jndi.fscontext.RefFSContextFactory";

    static {
        System.setProperty(javax.naming.Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, CONTEXT_FACTORY);
        System.setProperty(Context.PROVIDER_URL, URL);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        final InitialContext context = new InitialContext();
        final File file = (File) context.lookup("TestClass.java");
        System.out.println("File exists? " + file.exists());
    }
}
```

The output will be:

```
File exists? true
```

which is great. I am using RefFSContextFactory together with JNDI to get **File objects** from the context.

What I want to do is to be able to get **DataSource** objects, as in web applications. An example can be seen [here](https://www.mkyong.com/tomcat/how-to-configure-mysql-datasource-in-tomcat-6/).

I already have h2db running in my local, and the properties for it is as follows:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<Context>
    <Resource name="jdbc/studentform" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
              maxActive="5" maxIdle="10" maxWait="10000"
              username="sa" password="" driverClassName="org.h2.Driver"
              url="jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost:9092/~/h2dbs/studentform"/>
</Context>
```

But what jndi Factory implementation should I use and how do I define the URL in a standalone Java application?

Answer (score 0):

You need some container to run your application and provide it with such services as data source management etc. [Spring Framework](https://spring.io/) is the first that comes to mind in such cases. It allows you to create an IoC container that will manage your dependencies, [including data sources](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-sql.html). It also has [Spring Boot](http://projects.spring.io/spring-boot/) subproject that allows to create runnable modules easier.